# Cakephp 3.5 - Entity - Virtual Field not showing

Tags: cakephp, field, virtual

I have defined in an entity this :

```
protected $_virtual = [ 'full_name' ];

protected function _getFullName()
{
    return( $this->_properties['firstname'] . '  ' . $this->_properties['lastname'] );
}
```

But the full_name field is not retrieved by any query ( paginator or find('all') ) ... when the table is referred as an associated table.

The main table is GenPersons.
In that case, the field is showed correctly.
But then the I make

```
     $this->paginate = [ 'contain' => ['GenPersons'] ]
```

from the AerPilots controller ( AerPilots is a model ) ; and try to get the field as

```
     $aerPilot->gen_person->full_name;
```

nothing is showed.

Am I forgetting something ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
The problem was in the association on the model.
The GenPersons table belongs to General plugin.
The AerPilots table belongs to Aeronautical plugin.
When I baked the model for AerPilots, it generated this code :

```
    $this->belongsTo('GenPersons', [
        'foreignKey' => 'gen_person_id',
        'className' => '**Aeronautical**.GenPersons'
    ]);
```

And it must be :

```
    $this->belongsTo('GenPersons', [
        'foreignKey' => 'gen_person_id',
        'className' => '**General**.GenPersons'
    ]);
```